# How do I distinguish a variable passed as input to a function that's hardcoded, vs a locally defined variable?

Tags: python, libcst

If I have:

```
def my_func(x: str) -> void:
  //

def my_caller_func()-> void  
  local_var = "xyz"
  local_var_2 = "zzz"
  my_func(x=local_var)
```

I am trying to write a libcst visitor that will detect that the input value passed into my_func's x input is "xyz"

Is that possible?

Comment: not just a `if x == "xyz"` inside `my_func`?

Comment: would a decorator work for you?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to distinguish. As far as the CST is concerned, `my_func` is a function whose `x` parameter is bound to a `str` value; it does not know or care where that value will come from. You seem to be confusing the *parse* tree with the runtime call tree.

Comment: And don't write your question in a hybrid of Python and C(++). There is no type `void`, and comments do not start with `//`.

Comment: In the context of a CST, the *call* to `my_func` is constructed from a keyword argument  using a locally defined variable. The call, though, is independent of whatever definition the name `my_func` may have, which is a *semantic* consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you might find a decorator could do something like what you are looking to do (not knowing anything about `libcst`). You seem to want to be able to do *"something"* if the value passed to `my_func()` is `"xyz"` potentially without modification to `my_funct()`.

A decorator seems to fit the bill...

```py
def log_if_x_interesting(func):
    def inner(x):
        if x == "xyz":
            print("interesting")
        func(x=x)
    return inner

@log_if_x_interesting
def my_func(x: str):
    print(x)

def my_caller_func():
  local_var = "xyz"
  local_var_2 = "zzz"
  my_func(x=local_var)
  my_func(x=local_var_2)

my_caller_func()
```

That should give you:

```
interesting
xyz
zzz
```

If that would help.